# Microsoft sql server связи между таблицы

Tags: sql

microsoft sql server v18.10. есть база данных , не получается просмотреть связь между таблицами, помогите пожалуйста разобраться через , в интернете не нашел годный ответ. SHOW CREATE TABLE не работает

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE - это запрос, специфичный для MySQL. Ясен пень в SQL Server он не работает. Используйте SSMS или иное средство администрирования SQL Server.

Comment: @akina, я использую MSSM studio 18, но там тоже не нашел связи между таблицами .

Comment: Экспорт структуры в файл - и читай в своё удовольствие...

Comment: В MSSM есть функционал при нажатии ПКМ по таблице "Посмотреть зависимости"